# XSLT: How to process named siblings and 'jump' beyond them afterwards?

Tags: xml, xslt

In this xml:

```
<root>
 <a/>
 <b/>
 <c/>
 <x/>
 <b/>
 <c/>
 <a/>
</root>
```

I want to add an attribute to any a and any b or c in any combination that follow an a, until some other element is reached, like this:

```
<root>
  <a myattr='yes'/>
  <b myattr='yes'/>
  <c myattr='yes'/>
  <x/>
  <b/>
  <c/>
  <a myattr='yes'/>
</root>
```

Note the b or c that does not have a preceding a is ignored.
What I want is to process the a, then in its template do a for-each following-sibling::b or c and process those, but how do I then 'throw' the processing beyond those elements so that processing would start (in this example) at the x ?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The following XSLT stylesheet should produce the desired output.

When matching `b` and `c` elements, it looks for the first preceding `a` and "anything but `a`, `b`, and `c`" siblings and compares their positions. If the `a` sibling is most recent, then it adds the attribute.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="b|c">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::a | self::b | self::c)][1]/preceding-sibling::*) &lt;= count(preceding-sibling::a[1]/preceding-sibling::*)">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="myattr">yes</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a">
    <a myattr='yes'/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(self::a | self::b | self::c)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I believe <x> stands for "some other element".

Comment: Quite right. Thank you. I've edited my solution. My XPath gets longer still.

Comment: +1, that's pretty ingenious. I am not sure if you need to add another provision for a sequence **not** beginning with <a>. It's probably not an allowed input, but I thought it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a "one sibling at a time" tail recursion.  From your earlier question I gather you're working in XSLT 2.0, so you can do this quite elegantly using next-match

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:param name="inGroup"/>
  <xsl:next-match>
    <!-- a is always in a group -->
    <xsl:with-param name="inGroup" select="true()" />
  </xsl:next-match>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(self::a | self::b | self::c)]">
  <xsl:param name="inGroup"/>
  <xsl:next-match>
    <!-- anything other than a, b, c is never in a group -->
    <xsl:with-param name="inGroup" select="false()" />
  </xsl:next-match>
</xsl:template>

<!-- b and c will match this directly, and take their "groupiness" from the
     previous iteration -->
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:param name="inGroup"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:if test="$inGroup">
      <xsl:attribute name="myattr">yes</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
  <!-- process the next sibling, passing on the group flag -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]">
    <xsl:with-param name="inGroup" select="$inGroup" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

The same code should work in 1.0 except that you need to give the `*` template a `name` as well as a `match` and then use `call-template` instead of `next-match`.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to try this in XSLT 1.0:

```
...
<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="myattr">yes</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b|c">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="lineage">
            <xsl:call-template name="lineage"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:if test="$lineage = 'true'">
            <xsl:attribute name="myattr">yes</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="lineage">
<xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$i > count(preceding-sibling::*)"/>

    <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[$i])='a'">
        <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[$i])='b' 
                    or 
                    name(preceding-sibling::*[$i])='c'">
        <xsl:call-template name="lineage">
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i+1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```